# Find the difference to the closest higher number and the closest lower number in a list

Tags: c#, list, numbers, difference, closest

I have a list of int and I want to find the difference to the closest lower number and the difference to the closest higher number from a given referenceNumber. 
So in this case, if the referenceNumber is 5 . How could it output closestLowerNumber = 1 and closestHigherNumber = 3 ?

```
List<int> Test = new List<int>() {2, 1, 4, 8 };

        int referenceNumber = 5;
        int closestLowerNumber;
        int closestHigherNumber;
```

/* closestLowerNumber is the difference to the closest lower number (1)
closestHigherNumber is the difference to the closest higher number (3) */

Comment: what's the define of closestLowerNumber  and closestHigherNumber

Comment: @John Looks like it's supposed to return the absolute value of the difference of the number and it's closest neighbors. abs(8-5) = 3, abs(4-5) = 1.

Comment: @John why downvote? I want to return the difference to the numbers in the list, not the numbers in the list and first it should find the closest lower and closest higher number.

Comment: I'm not sure why you decided to blame some "John" for downvote as no one (except SO employees) have access to vote info... Instead you may want to think about why tooltip on downvote button says "this question does not show any research efforts"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this can be done in LINQ, it won't be the most efficient way to solve this task. I would go with something like this:

```
int referenceNumber = 5;
int? closestLowerNumber = null;
int? closestHigherNumber = null;

foreach (var i in Test)
{
    if (i < referenceNumber)
    {
        if (!closestLowerNumber.HasValue || closestLowerNumber < i)
        {
            closestLowerNumber = i;
        }
    }
    else if (i > referenceNumber)
    {
        if (!closestHigherNumber.HasValue || closestHigherNumber > i)
        {
            closestHigherNumber = i;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(
    $"{referenceNumber}:{referenceNumber - closestLowerNumber}:{closestHigherNumber - referenceNumber}");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following.

```
var closestLower = Test.Where(x=>x<referenceNum).Min(x=>referenceNum-x);
var closestHigher = Test.Where(x=>x>referenceNum).Min(x=>x-referenceNum);
```

Another option

```
var closestLower = referenceNum - Test.Where(x=>x<referenceNum).Max();
var closestHigher = Test.Where(x=>x>referenceNum).Min() - referenceNum;
```

Output
closestLower : 1
closestHigher : 3

Comment: Don't need the calculations in the min and max since you've already filtered for lesser and greater than.  Just find the outright max of the lesser set and the outright min of the greater set. =)

Comment: @Immersive Yeah, but that wouldn't give me the distance right ? The OP wanted the distance between reference numbers and max/min, and not the exact numbers.

Comment: `Test.Where(x=>x<num).Max()` gives you the biggest number that's smaller than the reference.  If you want the 'distance' then it's just `dist = num - closestSmallestValue`

Comment: yes, could have that as well. That would reduce calculation for each element as well. But would have to change the min/max call a bit too. Will update the answer with that option as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a semi-efficient way of doing it (depending on the data, it might be more efficient without sorting):

```
var test = new List<int>() { 2, 1, 4, 8 };
int referenceNumber = 5;
int closestLowerNumber = 0;
int closestHigherNumber = 0;

foreach (var val in test.OrderBy(v => v))
{
    if (val < referenceNumber)
    {
        closestLowerNumber = val;
    }
    else if (val > referenceNumber)
    {
        closestHigherNumber = val;
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Closest low: {0}, Closest high: {1}, Distance low: {2}, Distance high: {3}", closestLowerNumber, closestHigherNumber, (referenceNumber - closestLowerNumber), (closestHigherNumber - referenceNumber)));
```

Outputs:

```
Closest low: 4, Closest high: 8, Distance low: 1, Distance high: 3
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/BUDR10860)

Note that this assumes there is at least 1 number smaller and 1 number bigger. If that's not the case `closestLowerNumber` or `closestHigherNumber` will remain 0 and give weird results. Therefore it's probably wise to use a nullable int instead, so that you can check if it has been set (`int? closestLowerNumber`) using `closestLowerNumber.HasValue`.

Comment: Thanks very much!. Any idea how to solve it without sorting?

Comment: @Roblogic Kirill's method :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically Kirill's answer, but cleaner:

```
var Test = new List<int>() { 2, 1, 4, 8 };
var reference = 5;

var closestLower = int.MinValue;
var closestHigher = int.MaxValue;

foreach (var value in Test) {
    switch (value.CompareTo(reference)) {
        case -1: // value < reference
            closestLower = Math.Max(closestLower, value);
            break;
        case 0: // value == reference
            break;
        case 1: // value > reference
            closestHigher = Math.Min(closestHigher, value);
            break;
    }
}
```